# Problem overriding ACL for default group ownership

Tags: permissions, acl

I am unable to override previously set ACL settings.

This is what it looks like:

```
root@ip-xxx-xxx:/srv/www# getfacl grace.staging.site.com.au/
# file: grace.staging.site.com.au/
# owner: web
# group: www-data
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:www-data:rwx
group:dev:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:www-data:rwx <---------
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

As you can see, the default group is `default:group:www-data:rwx` - this setting has been applied recursively. However, each time I create a new file or directory, they're attributed to `luqo33:dev`:

```
luqo33@ip-xxx-xxx:/srv/www/grace.staging.site.com.au$ touch test_file
luqo33@ip-xxx-xxx:/srv/www/grace.staging.site.com.au$ ls -al
total 20
drwxrwxr-x+ 3 web    www-data 4096 Jun 28 19:14 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 web    www-data 4096 Jun 28 18:33 ..
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 web    www-data 4096 Jun 28 18:33 logs
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 luqo33 dev         0 Jun 28 19:14 test_file <-------
```

I need to make all files and directories to be owned by `web:www-data`. Clearly, in spite of the fact that there is default ACL for the group (`www-data`), it does not have any effect. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what the `default` entry means on a ACL; if you look at the new file you created you'll see it already has an ACL (the `+` at the end of the ls output), and a `getfacl test_file` will show it has `group:www-data:rwx` associated with it.

If you want the newly created file to be *owned* by `www-data` then you need to add the setgid bit on the directory.

Without the flag, if I create a file then it's in my group:

```
$ ls -ld .
drwxr-xr-x 2 sweh www-data 4096 Jun 28 17:37 ./

$ touch x
$ ls -l x
-rw-r--r-- 1 sweh sweh 0 Jun 28 17:38 x
```

I now add the setgid bit to the directory and the new file has group ownership defaulting to www-data

```
$ sudo chmod g+s .
$ ls -ld .
drwxr-sr-x 2 sweh www-data 4096 Jun 28 17:38 ./

$ touch y
$ ls -l y
-rw-r--r-- 1 sweh www-data 0 Jun 28 17:38 y
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. Is it possible at all to achieve the `g+s`  functionality with ACL only?

Comment: I don't _think_ so; the manpage for `setfacl` only mentions `rwx`.